# How to access this server?

Tags: ping, networking, nslookup

I have a server that I cannot access. At first I thought it was just some temporary failure with the server, but checking from other IP addresses reveals that it is working just fine. It's only my IP address that's failing.

So here is what I've tried:

- **nslookup** - resolves correctly
- **ping** - 100% packet loss using the IP address or domain
- **traceroute** - first few hops work, but from about 6 and on, I just get stars

**Edit:** I am using OpenDNS for DNS resolution, and as mentioned above, the problem is not DNS resolution anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you might have intermediate DNS issues (i.e your ISP is having some DNS resolution issues). Probably best contact them to check, and/or report a fault.

Comment: @Ben: I use OpenDNS for DNS resolution.

Comment: I have renewed my IP address, restarted my PC, router, and modem. Still nothing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you temporarily change your DNS servers to 8.8.8.8 (Google's public DNS servers) does the website work?

Comment: @Ben: Nope. Other sites work.

Comment: r u trying to remote into the server?

Comment: @dasko: No, I just trying to access it over HTTP. It's a web server. I can access it via a proxy, but not my own IP address.

Comment: @ George Edision, ok, i had this happen before with an rdc session and it was hung packets in my router, when i did was just unplug my router and wait 30 seconds, plug it back and i was able to continue on to the sessions. anyways good luck.

Comment: @dasko: I unplugged the router for a good long time (like a minute) and it still won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I fixed it!**

I finally got it working by going into my router's config page and forcing it to renew its IP address.

Comment: @John: Sorry. I forgot about this question.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a firewall in place doing something. I would turn off the firewall and see if that alters things at all.

Alternatively, can other IPs access your target system via HTTP? If they can and your firewall isn't doing anything, then I would clear your cookies, cache, etc.